# Managing multiple custom variations of the same app (GIT?)

Tags: git

Good Morning All,

I have an application that I've developed.  I have specific customers that want a customized version of this app.  I am trying to find a way to fork the core app and make this customization, but still be able to apply patches that I make for the core app.

For example:

**Core app has a 3 x 3 grid of buttons.  Each button is able to be customized in the settings (color, text, etc).**

**Customer Joe wants this grid to be 2 x 2.  This affects that XML layouts as well as a considerable amount of code that handles these buttons.**

How would I make a new version for Joe, but allow it to be updated when I update the core app?

Also, if I make changes to the button handling in the core app, I may not want these changes to apply downstream.  Is there a way to flag them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I really don't want to try and manage two unlinked sets of code.

Thank you,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a separate branch for joe.

For example you can do your main development on branch `master` and have the customized version on branch `joe`.

Now you can develop your app by adding commits to `master` and updating branch `joe` by merging the changes from `master`.

The workflow would be something like this:

```
git checkout -b joe master  # create branch
# customize the code for joe
git commit                  # commit the customization
git checkout master
# add a new feature to your app
git commit -am 'new feature'
git checkout joe
git merge master
```

Most of the time the merge just works. If you did change parts, that are customized for joe, you probably get a merge conflict and have to resolve it manually using `git mergetool`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am new to GIT, and am using the EGIT plugin for Eclipse to manage my code.  I was able to make a branch for Joe, but I'm not sure how to jump between the versions in eclipse.  No mater which branch I chose, the code remains the same.

Comment: Hmmmm....I merged the master, and it did say I had conflicts, but overwrote everything.  Any additional advice would be appreciated.

Comment: My advice: Don't use egit for actively working on your branches unless you understand exactly what each option is doing. Have a look at `gitk --all` to get an idea what it did.

Comment: For me it's not an issue with egit, but with git commands in general.  Will manually entering the git commands give me a clearer idea of what is going on?